# NSIS installer License page only shows "Close" and "Cancel" buttons

Tags: windows, user-interface, macros, installation, nsis

I've built a simple installer on Windows using NSIS 2.46.
That is the code for the license page

```
# UI
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_RADIOBUTTONS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "..\legal\disclaimer.txt"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

When I run the installer, the License page displays the license text properly but only has a disabled "Close" and an enabled "Cancel" button. Once I change the selected radio button to "I accept the terms of the License Agreement", the "Close" button is enabled. Both buttons cause the installer to quit if I click them.

How can I change the script to have a "Continue" button if the license is accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a installer with just a license page is rather pointless, everything should behave normally if you add another page after it:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_RADIOBUTTONS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

It is not recommended to create a installer without a InstFiles page but it can be done:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_RADIOBUTTONS
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW SetNextBtnTextToInstall
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE DoInstall
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function SetNextBtnTextToInstall
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1
${NSD_SetText} $0 "$(^InstallBtn)"
FunctionEnd

Function DoInstall
MessageBox mb_ok "Install would take place here..."
SetErrorLevel 0
Quit
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Adding another page did the trick. I just don't fully understand why displaying only a license is pointless. I had a basic installer before without any MUI elements. It just started the installation and showed a progress bar. I thought - since the customer wanted to display a license - that adding a license page would be sufficient and anything else should run as before. However I added the page MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES which turned out to be a good looking progress bar and everything worked perfectly. Thank you Anders!